# Android NDK + LibEvents

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I'm attempting to develop an android native glue application that uses LibEvents.
I obtained an android friendly build of LibEvents from here...
https://github.com/ventureresearch/libevent

My android.mk file is almost identical (other than relative paths).

It successfully compiles as a **static** library and links into my own **shared** library.
However when I attempt to execute I get an error from Dalvik indicating it cannot load my shared library.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16123): Process: com.marty.socketclient1, PID: 16123
E/AndroidRuntime(16123): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marty.socketclient1/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.marty.socketclient1-1/libSocketClient1.so
```

My native code functions correctly if I do not use my build of LibEvents.
Also note that if I remove all the existing source files from LibEvents and add a new module with my own function and *just* call that in my shared library then everything behaves.
This leads me to believe it is being correctly built (or at least the compile/link flags does not themselves prohibiting loading).

**ndk-depends** reports no additional shared object dependencies so I thought that maybe there is some errant code being executed in LibEvents as dlopen is executing.
I tried replacing the LibEvents logging mechanism with android logging but I'm getting no further output.

Neither can I find any occurrences of

```
__attribute__((__constructor__))
```

or

```
_init
```

in the LibEvents source code.

Note that LibEvents is just 'C' library so there can't be statically initialised objects as with C++ (or am I incorrect in this assumption?).

Are there any other means of executing functionality at load time that I'm unaware of?
Any ideas what I can check next?
Are there any further logging options I can enable that might provide further insight?

I also distilled the android.mk file (as below) to the minimum to allow me to just call:

```
evutil_make_socket_nonblocking()
```

And still suffer the issue with being unable to load the library.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libevents
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=      \
    ../evutil.c         \
    ../event.c          \
    ../log.c            \
    ../evthread.c       \
    ../evmap.c          \
    ../signal.c         \
    ../epoll.c          \
    ../poll.c           \
    ../evutil_rand.c    \
    ../select.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH) \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../android \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DANDROID -fvisibility=hidden   
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -fvisibility=hidden

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else suffers this issue, here's the solution.

It was a long process but I stubbed functions and isolated modules until I could reproduce the problem with just one source file.
I then commented out code until I found the errant call that caused my library not to load.

It turns out to be this...

```
long _evutil_weakrand(void)
{
  return random();
}
```

And in fact if I created any function that calls random() then my shared object failed to load.

Apparently this relates to the android level.  You need to use level 19, I was using level 21.

Relates to this...
[Android NDK: load_library: cannot locate srand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475055/android-ndk-load-library-cannot-locate-srand)